# What is a p-wave superconductor in 1-dimension often referred in the Kitaev model? What term in the hamiltonian makes it P wave?

Tags: superconductivity, topological-insulators, majorana-fermions, spin-orbit

I am currently reading papers related to Majorana zero modes observation in 1D nanowire systems. I am very new to the field and I read everywhere that the presence of spin-orbit interaction, magnetic field, and superconductivity makes the wire essentially similar to the spinless p-wave superconducting hamiltonian described by Kitaev. First of all what does p-wave pairing means and how spin orbit and Zeeman field make a wire essentially spinless? How to understand it intuitively?
[image: Kitaev toy model]